# how to search strictly in mongodb?

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have a collection in which 70 documents are present like this:-

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("629090f9772c8f43cd264662"), 
    "songName" : "Deep End",
    "albumName": "Deep End"
},
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("629090f9772c8f43cd264665"), 
    "songName" : "Deep Blue", 
    "albumName": "Pages"
},
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("629090f9772c8f43cd264665"), 
    "songName" : "The World", 
    "albumName": "Deep End"
},
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("629090f9772c8f43cd264665"), 
    "songName" : "The River",
    "albumName": "A Different Kind Of Human - Step 2"
}
```

I want to search strictly through these 70 documents, as of now my code looks like this:-

```
db.songDetails.aggregate([{$search:{index:"searchDB",text:{query:"deep end",path:{"wildcard":"*"}}}}])
```

when I run this, I'm getting results as:-

```
[
  {
    "_id" : ObjectId("629090f9772c8f43cd264662"), 
    "songName" : "Deep End",
    "albumName": "Deep End"
  },
  { 
    "_id" : ObjectId("629090f9772c8f43cd264665"), 
    "songName" : "Deep Blue",  
    "albumName": "Pages"
  },
  { 
    "_id" : ObjectId("629090f9772c8f43cd264665"), 
    "songName" : "The World",  
    "albumName": "Deep End"
  }
]
```

But I only want the result as

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("629090f9772c8f43cd264662"), 
    "songName" : "Deep End",
    "albumName": "Deep End"
},
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("629090f9772c8f43cd264665"), 
    "songName" : "The World",  
    "albumName": "Deep End"
}
```

I mean, I need the ***exact search*** for the query from any *field* *{it may be from "songName" or "albumName"}*, how can I do this?

Thank you:)

Comment: db.songDetails.find({"songName" : "Deep End"})

Comment: You can also use the aggregate stage: `$match: { songName : "Deep End" }`

Comment: hey @prasad_  I think I have asked my question in the wrong way, I have updated the code and my question. do you know how can I do that? sorry && thankyou:)

Comment: You can use the `$or` operator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the answer if anyone is searching for the same query:-
as @prasad_ mentioned you can use `$or` operator, like this:-

*Note:- the query is case-sensitive*

```
var search="Deep End"
db.songDetails.find({$or:[{songName:search},{albumName:search}]})
```

In case you want to search the query in-case sensitive then you can use regex as follows:-

```
db.songDetails.find({$or:[{songName:{$regex:/deep end/i}},{albumName:{$regex:/deep end/i}}]})
```

make sure that you have added **i** in the regex thing as it makes your query in-case sensitive and note that this will cause every entry containing *deep end* to match the query (deep end, deep end XYZ, deep end now)